# "Display Background value "0" raster"

Tags: raster, geoserver, erdas-imagine

While publish raster layer in geoserver it shows background as black. How to remove the black color. if there is any options to permanently remove the black color.

Comment: you need to create an alpha channel

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html

this link to used for Raster background null

Comment: Please don't just post a link to a site. Add details here and then link.